# Get current IST time in php

Tags: php

I am using the following code to get current IST time. But it only gives the system time. I changed my system time due to some reason. So i get only system time instead of current time.

```
$time_now=mktime(date('h')+5,date('i')+30,date('s'));
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i', $time_now);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Set your system time correctly, so your system knows its correct timezone and the correct time there. In PHP, set your desired timezone, then just print the date:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('d-m-Y H:i');
```

Don't do manual offset calculations unless you know exactly what you're doing, it's way too fickle.

Comment: This also outputs system time only

Comment: If your system is in India and you set the timezone to Kolkata, then yes, it'll give you the system time. What other time do you expect? Please clarify.

Comment: Actually i changed my system time. Current time in my system is 3.40 am 12-11-2012

Comment: Well, I don't know what time it's *supposed* to be... But PHP can't magically know what time it is in India. It bases all its time calculations **on the system time**. If your system time is off, PHP's time calculations will be off as well. It's not magic, there's only one clock on your system, and you have to set it correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Get exact Current Indian Time in PHP

```
$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

//If you want Day,Date with time AM/PM
echo $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a T");

//Get Only Current Time 00:00 AM / PM 
echo $today = date("g:i a");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **now()** method it gave current time.

$query = "UPDATE (table name) SET (column) = **now()**  WHERE (condition)";

**Note**: *Make sure that type of the column in the database must be* **DATETIME** *type.*

Comment: This question is from 2012 and already has an accepted answer, unless there is a new solution that appeares with a new PHP version, there is no need to answer again. Also, there is no point in involving SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

To get the user current time you will need javascript.
if you want to make default timezone on your pages you can use `date_default_timezone_set`

You can read about this in: [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_default_timezone_set` :

```
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
}

echo date('Y-m-d h-i-s');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Notice:** `date_default_timezone_set()`: Timezone ID `'Asia/Mumbai'` is invalid in `D:\Program Files\wamp\www\PHP\...`

Only `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata')` is Showing Valid In PHP 5.4.16 Ver :)
:)

Answer (score 0):

```
// set the timezone first
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
}

$date = date("m/d/Y");
echo $date;
```

Before adding the date function use the timezone declaration first.

Answer (score -1):

Set your system time correctly, so your system knows its correct timezone and the correct time there. In PHP, set your desired timezone, then just print the date:

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('d-m-Y H:i');